# CSS to align grid elements from loop post

Tags: php, html, css

I am slowly but surely getting the look of my site figured out. But I am having a bit of trouble with the CSS of the grids.

I managed to get the grid laid out with simple divs, but I have a common problem where if I have a Title that takes up more than one line, it throws off the alignment and looks sloppy. How would I go about fixing something like this?

I would like the top of the text blocks to all be aligned with each other. In line with the bottom of the longest most Title block.

Here is the code I am using

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

// The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.

    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

// If there was an error, continue to the next term.
if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
    continue;
}

// We successfully got a link. Print it out.
echo '<div class="my-grid"><li><h2><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' .     $term->name . '</a></h2><br/>';
echo  $term->description; // This will return the description of the term
echo '</li></div>';
}

CSS: .my-grid { float:left; width: 270px; margin: 0 2.5% 1em 0;}
```

Sample: http://dev.unicriscreations.com/collection/

Comment: A Javascript pass to find the biggest title in each row and set all the others to the same height might be a good idea.

Comment: Check these, `http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/equal-heights/` and `http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/`.

Comment: For a start your rendered HTML is invalid. The only valid child of `ul` is `li`. You can have pretty much anything you like in the `li` but `li` must be the direct child of `ul`

Answer (score 0):

You can use several approaches here:

**Limiting with PHP**
In this case, you'll make sure your title doesn't exceed a number of characters. You can use the following code in your functions.php file

```
function the_titlesmall($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $length = false) { $title = get_the_title();

    if ( $length && is_numeric($length) ) {
        $title = substr( $title, 0, $length );
    }

    if ( strlen($title)> 0 ) {
        $title = apply_filters('the_titlesmall', $before . $title . $after, $before, $after);
        if ( $echo )
            echo $title;
        else
            return $title;
    }
}
```

**Limiting with CSS**

```
h2 {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**Showing all with CSS**

```
h2 {
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
}
```

In this case it will show 3 lines of text, if you need a 4th, you'll need to change each line by adding 40px, thus 160px. But of course, you'll see the issues behind this solution. I usually use the PHP one, but there you go